# What happened to Asgardian refugees in Infinity war?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

In *Thor: Ragnarok* we see all Asgardians get into a refugee ship and meeting with a huge ship. Thanos had mandated that half of people from a conquered planet to be executed and the other half to be spared. But all Asgardians seem dead. When Thor and Loki have been defeated we see bodies and a spreading and toxic indoor fire. When the Guardians arrive, we see bodies thrown out into the cold vacuum. Did Thanos's guys use excessive force and kill everybody?

Answer (score 4):

**Did Thanos's guys use excessive force and kill everybody?**

Not every Asgardian is dead but few survived. From my own [answer about Valkyrie:](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/88528/1190)

> From [comicbook.com](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/88528/1190):
>
> > According to the [Redditor](https://www.reddit.com/r/marvelstudios/comments/8g10pg/joe_russo_came_and_had_a_qa_at_our_high_school/), Russo confirmed Valkyrie did survive Thanos’ ambush of the Sanctuary II. The director did not say how, but he did say a portion of the Asgardians also survived. Russo said escape pods ferried those survivors away from the battle, giving the Asgardian race the chance to escape extinction. It is very possible the Valkyrie was charged with overseeing that evacuation since most of the Asgardian refugees were simple civilians.

And also Thor said the same in film itself:

> **Thor:** There's six stones out there. Thanos already has the Power Stone because he stole it last week, when he decimated Xandar. He stole the Space Stone from me, when he destroyed my ship and **slaughtered half my people**. The Time and Mind Stones are safe on Earth. They're with the Avengers. <sub>[source](http://transcripts.wikia.com/wiki/Avengers:_Infinity_War)</sub>